# Did the Rama change a Minhag regarding Mikvah?

Tags: minhag, mikvah-ritual-bath, rama

I heard a story where the Rama visited a town that had a harmful minhag of the person (man) in charge of the mikvah asking women if they went to the mikvah, then relating the response to the husbands (or something similar). The Rama promptly stopped this minhag.

I'm having trouble remembering where I saw it - is it a true story? Any sources are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Lev Haivri*  writes when the Rema  was accepted as  Rav in Krakow, there had a strange Minhag in the city.

The morning after a woman went to the Mikvah, the Mikvah Lady’s husband,
wished  the husband (wife who went to the Mikva)   ” Mazal Tov.”

The Rema held this Minhag to be boorish and non Tzanua, so he abolished it.

There was a person who was out of town and wasn’t aware of the abolishment of the  Minhag.

One day he angrily approached the Mikvah lady’s husband and complained to him why he had not wished him Mazal Tov. The Mikvah lady’s husband answered

"For two reasons,
a) The new Rav abolished the Minhag
b) your wife never went to the Mikva that night”.

When the Rema heard this, he realized the reason for this strange Minhag.

He also realized his mistake and regretted having abolished the Minhag.

To compensate for his mistake The Rema decided to collect all Minhagei Yisroel.
Hence his Chibur of the Mapah on the Shulchan Aruch.**

- R. Akiva Yosef Schlesinger (Talmid of the Chasam Sofer)
  **  Story recorded in the Krakow Kehilla Pinkas(Journal

Source, with original Hebrew text can be found here

http://torasaba.blogspot.com/2019/04/mazel-tov-story-of-rema-in-krakow.html?m=1